# Generate token console for Intune datawarehouse

Tags: c#, token, intune, microsoft-identity-web

Here's the code snippet pulled from Microsoft Learn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/data-warehouse-app-only-auth-)

It seems the line with AuthenticationContext, ClientCredential and SecureClientSecret are depreciated. For example: **ClientCredential' is obsolete: 'Use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.WithCertificate or WithClientSecret instead.** I cannot get this code snippet to work.

```
using System.Security;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;


    class IntuneDataWarehouse
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Intune Datawarehouse Start");
    
            var applicationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"].ToString();
            SecureString applicationSecret = ConvertToSecureStr(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appKey"].ToString()); // Load as SecureString from configuration file or secret store (i.e. Azure KeyVault)
            var tenantDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantDomain"].ToString();
            var msalContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/" + tenantDomain + "/oauth2/token");
    
             AuthenticationResult authResult = msalContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
             resource: "https://api.manage.microsoft.com/",
             clientCredential: new ClientCredential(
                 applicationId,
                 new SecureClientSecret(applicationSecret))).Result;
    
            Console.WriteLine("End of run");
        }
```

Has anyone worked on similar code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) (now considered obsolete), consider [`Microsoft.Identity.Client` (MSAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client?view=msal-dotnet-latest) and [`ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder?view=msal-dotnet-latest), which is the recommended way to acquire tokens for applications. That method supports both client secrets and certificates for authentication.

Similar to [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/main/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L57-L136), or [this one](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-exchange-docs/blob/main/docs/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth.md#get-a-token-with-app-only-auth) (to get a token), your code would be:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class IntuneDataWarehouse
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Intune Datawarehouse Start");

        // Configuration parameters
        var applicationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"];
        var applicationSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appKey"];
        var tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]; // Make sure your configuration has tenantId
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
        var scope = new string[] { "https://api.manage.microsoft.com/.default" }; // Using /.default for app permissions

        // Build the MSAL client
        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(applicationId)
            .WithClientSecret(applicationSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        // Acquire token
        var authResult = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Token acquired: " + authResult.AccessToken);
        Console.WriteLine("End of run");
    }
}
```

Remember to update your app's registration in Azure AD to include permissions for Microsoft Intune and grant admin consent for those permissions.

The authority URL is changed to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`, which is the recommended format.
For app-only authentication, the scope is defined using `https://api.manage.microsoft.com/.default`. That scope indicates that the application is requesting the permissions defined directly in the Azure portal for the app.
The `Main` method is asynchronous (`async Task`), to properly await the asynchronous call to `AcquireTokenForClient`.

Comment: Thank you- will make edits tomorrow evening when I get on my laptop. Will update this post and bounty then.